# How to convert 96dpi to 300dpi with GraphicsMagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have the following code to convert a 96dpi image to 300dpi

```
  gm(writer.toBuffer())
    .filter("Point")
    .density(96,96)
    .resample(300, 300)
    .quality(100)
    .antialias(false)  
    .toBuffer(function(err,buffer){ 
        res.write(buffer); 
        res.end();      
    });
```

the output doesn't look like 300dpi.
My main question is am I using density and resample correctly?
I realize I could use a better filter but am trying to keep the time down.

Comment: A 300DPI image has more "detail" than a 96DPI image, because it contains 10 times as many pixels/dots for the same print size. If you take a 96DPI image and make it a 300DPI image of the same print size size, this doesn't create detail out of the blue, and you are just spreading one pixel of the source over 10pixels of the target. You have more pixels but the image is roughly the same.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Yeah, I get the fact you cannot introduce quality where there was none. I guess what I have a hard time wrapping my head around is, if a have a 8.5xX11 inch image  ate 96dpi, if I look at the stats in a browser, the image is 816 px x 1056px. When printed out, it is 8.5x11 as is should be...

Comment: ... Now, say I want that exact same image to be 300dpi. Does that mean. in the browser, it will be 2550px X 3300px? If so, doesn't that mean it will download and print at a much greater size than 8.5 x 11? I've read DPI has to relevance when talking about display in a monitor, but this is what the user will print out, and they need it 8.5 x 11in @300dpi. In my head, it will print out too large.

Comment: If you need 8.5 by 11 @300DPI you indeed need 2550px X 3300px (wihich is 8.5Mpix, within the reach of any current smartphone). The "DPI" is really a metadata of the image, the real data is the pixels. See [this](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Image-size-in-Gimp). Written for Gimp, but explains a few things.

Comment: Thank you so much. Makes prefect sense. I think the fog is clearing n my head.